# Ansible - Unable to get remote hostname

Tags: ansible

here my playbook.yml:

```
- hosts: oph-server
  roles:
    - role: 'myrole'
      server_hostname: "{{ansible_hostname}}"
      io_hostnames: "{{ groups['oph-io']|map('extract', hostvars, 'ansible_hostname')|list }}"
      io_ips: "{{ groups['oph-io']|map('extract', hostvars, 'ansible_default_ipv4')|list if 'oph-io' in groups else []}}"

- hosts: oph-io
  roles:
    - role: 'myrole'
      server_hostname: "{{ hostvars['oph-server']['ansible_hostname'] }}"
      io_hostnames: "{{ groups['oph-io']|map('extract', hostvars, 'ansible_hostname')|list if 'oph-io' in groups else []}}"
      io_ips: "{{ groups['oph-io']|map('extract', hostvars, ['ansible_default_ipv4', 'address'])|list if 'oph-io' in groups else []}}"
```

and this is the inventory

```
[oph-io]
oph-io1 ansible_default_ipv4=A.B.C.D
[oph-server]
oph-server ansible_default_ipv4=E.F.G:H
```

No issues on the `oph-io` node, while on the `oph-server` I'm able to properly get the `io_ips`, but the io_hostnames is `UNDEFINED`.

What's wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ansible_hostname` and `ansible_default_ipv4` are a computed facts with the [`setup` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/setup_module.html) or the play keyword `gather_facts: yes`.

A play only gather facts of the targeted hosts, so facts from `oph-io` are not yet gathered.
To gather facts of other hosts (or not yet gathered by another play before), you can use the `setup` module with delegation and fact delegation like documented https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#delegated-facts:

```yaml
- hosts: oph-server
  pre_tasks:
    - name: gather facts from oph-io
      setup:
      delegate_to: "{{ item }}"
      delegate_facts: true
      loop: "{{ groups['oph-io'] }}"
  roles:
    - role: 'myrole'
[...]
```

To define the machine IP or host to connect to, the parameter is `ansible_host`, as documented in [ansible inventory documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/network/getting_started/first_inventory.html).

Comment: `gather_facts: yes` should be the default. I also tried to explicitly set it, but it didn't work. Anyway, `ansible_hostname` seems to be properly working for `oph-io`

Comment: You're trying to access gathered facts of another group (`oph-io`) than the group of the play (`oph-server`)
If they were not gathered by a play before, they don't have facts yet! You can add before everything an empty play targeting hosts `oph-io:oph-server` just to gather facts of everyone. Or explicitly call the `setup` module with delegation to the hosts of `oph-io` to retrieve their facts before accessing them.